# Probabilty of 2 buses or more arriving at a bus s top at the same time

Tags: probability

I do have a basic understanding of laws of probability, but need assistance with figuring out this question

This is a general question that applies to all bus stops-  As you know the length of red curb at bus stops depends on the number of buses that utilize it, the frequency, length of buses, and how long they stay ( and other factors like possibly a distribution model of arrival times since they do not always work like clock-work)
How do we  manage the odds of 2 or more buses arriving at the same time at the same bus stop?
Do we just increase red curb for all shared stops or if odds are low ( to be defined), or just install enough red curb for one bus.

1- bus A arrives every X  min
2-bus B  arrives every y min
 3- bus c arrives every z min

they stay at a stop on average (X min) 1 min or less
since buses don't run like clockwork. how do I calculate this?

Answer (score 0):

The simple thing is to assume that the buses arrive randomly and independently at the indicated rates.  Then if you allow time $t$ for the stop, the probability that bus A is there is $\frac tX$, the probability bus B is there is $\frac ty$, and the probability that both are there is $\frac {t^2}{Xy}$ and so on.  The assumption may not be valid.  If the buses are on the same route, if the first gets behind it slows more picking up more passengers, while the second runs ahead because there aren't so many to pick up.  Maybe there is construction on a common part of the route.